# iOS app hangs forever when going to "CS50" or "CS50 Meta"

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app

When I go to the "[CS50](https://cs50.stackexchange.com/)" or "[CS50 Meta](https://cs50.meta.stackexchange.com/)" sites (which can be reached from the left drawer → More Sites), the app hangs forever.

[image: Screenshot]

I'm forced to kill the app. No good.

Version: Stack Exchange iOS App Version 1.0.0, 1.0.1.70

Comment: Also reproduced in version 1.0.0.67

Comment: There's a funny problem at play here.  Working on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed in the next build.  There was a problem in some code that *used to* run in a background thread that said filter and if there's not enough results load the next page of results.  This of course spun forever if that was the last page of results.

I was halfway through fixing those problems when I saw a `FIXME` saying I could just nuke that whole block.

Comment: Verified fixed in 1.0.1.71.